# Add background color for bootstrap-vue carousel image

Tags: html, css, vuejs2, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to add a layer of color filter on top of my slideshow images. I am using the bootstrap-vue/webpack for my showcase website development. The code within my components is:

HTML:

```
        <b-carousel id="carousel1"
                style="text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #333;"
                controls
                indicators
                background="#f85752"
                :interval="4000"
                img-width="1024"
                img-height="300"
                v-model="slide"
                @sliding-start="onSlideStart"
                @sliding-end="onSlideEnd"
                class ="mycarousel"
    >
        <b-carousel-slide class="item">
            <img slot="img" class="d-block img-fluid w-100"
                 src="./images/amdufake012.jpg" alt="factory picture">
        </b-carousel-slide>
        <!-- slides with image -->
        <b-carousel-slide>
            <img slot="img" class="d-block img-fluid w-100"
                 src="./images/cargo_securing_airbag.jpg" alt="baggie">
        </b-carousel-slide>
    </b-carousel>
```

CSS:

```
img{
    background-color: #f85752;
}
```

I try to this method to add background color on top of my slideshow image. It doesn't work. What are the other ways to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding the `background-colour` to the image directly, I recommend creating a new sibling element, and giving that the background, along with  `position: absolute` and `opacity: 0.5`.

```css
.image-overlay {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f85752;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<b-carousel-slide>
  <div class="image-overlay"></div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100">
</b-carousel-slide>
```

Comment: I tested it, and it only cover part of the image. I have used margin and padding to move around, and it still cannot cover the entire image.